# Access Violation in pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointer-arithmetic

With the code:

```
int nsize;
int * buffer;
char TargetBuffer[4096];
const SIZE_T buffersize = (320*240) * sizeof(int);


buffer = (int *) malloc(bufferSize);
// fill buffer with data

nsize = 0;
while(nsize < buffersize)
{
    // HERE after some loops i get Access Violation
    memcpy(TargetBuffer, buffer + nsize, 4096);


    // do stuff with TargetBuffer
    nsize += 4096;
}
```

Why am I get the Access Violation? What should I change?

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? Have you checked, in the debugger, the value of `nsize` and compared it to `bufferSize`?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that after nsize > (75 * 4096) you access invalid addresses? - Maybe it'd help if you tell us what the code is intended to do?

Comment: You are mixing different units of measure. Some sizes are in `sizeof(int)` units and others are in bytes. Pick one unit and stick to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you add `buffer + nsize` you have to realize that you are actually adding `buffer + (nsize * (sizeof(int))` since it's a `int *` when you are doing pointer arithmetic.

So it probably has something to do with it. Try incrementing nsize by `nsize += 4096/sizeof(int)` or something more clever.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: No, SIZE_T is type of the `buffersize` variable and that does not appear in the faulty calculation. The type of `buffer` is `int *`, so `buffer + nsize` moves the pointer by `nsize * sizeof(int)`.

Comment: when `nsize` become `116736` i got Access Violation ( ater i done the `4096/sizeof(int)`)

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
SIZE_T left = buffersize;
nsize = 0;

while(left)
{
    SIZE_T block = (left >= 4096)?4096:left;
    // HERE after some loops i get Access Violation
    memcpy(TargetBuffer, buffer, block);
    buffer += (left) / sizeof(*buffer);

    // do stuff with TargetBuffer
    left -= block;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem you see is that you are going over the edge because your code isn't taking care of sizes that are not multiples of the 4K.

Comment: doesn't `SIZE_T block = (left >= 4096)?4096:left;` needs `?` ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your `while` loop as

```
while(nsize < (buffersize/sizeof(int))
```

`buffer` is for `int`s and not `char`. `int` takes multiple bytes, you are over counting and copying from memory which is not part of `buffer`.